# Upgrading from oracle 11g to 12c

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, oracle12c

i have a project to do a migration from oracle 11g to 12c but I do not know where I should start please how can I do this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start this large task by reading the manual.  In this case, read the [Database Upgrade Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/index.html).